# logging various actions on a site. flexible way

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have to log different actions on site. For example, CRUD operations. It's not simple message: "Entity is saved". For different entity various parameters. For example, when changing user I have to save ID, personal number also, for business trip entity I have to save begin and end dates of business trip. This is my code for updating user:

```
public UserController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Update(...)
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
          ...
           var id =  _repository.SaveOrUpdate(user);
            _eventLogger.WriteEventLog(new EventLoggerData
                    {
                        EventType = EventLogType.Update,
                        ObjectType = ObjectType.User,
                        ObjectId = id,
                        EventData = _jsonObjectMapper.ToJson(new NumberedEventLoggerData
                        {                                
                            Number = number
                        })
                    });
       }
   }
}
```

All works fine. But the code :

```
 _eventLogger.WriteEventLog(new EventLoggerData
       {
             EventType = EventLogType.Update,
             ObjectType = ObjectType.User,
             ObjectId = id,
             EventData = _jsonObjectMapper.ToJson(new NumberedEventLoggerData
                 {
                    Number = number
                 })
        });
```

is the big and this piece of the code will be repeated more than once. I have about 20 controllers and each with CRUD operations.

May be there are more flexible way?
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create more WriteEventLog overloads to make code in controllers simpler; something like WriteEventLog(User), for all the occasions.

2) What kind of ORM do you use? EntityFramework has SavingChanges event, for example, where you can examine changes that are made and log them (I've done this and it worked well)

3) Have a look at PostSharp (http://www.postsharp.net/), it may allow you to move logging completely out of controllers with just an attribute.

Comment: I use NHibernate. I know about interceptors in EF. But this logger must be used not only for CRUD.

Comment: I'm not familiar with nHibernate, doesn't it have similar event? Using this approach would not block you from calling logger directly for non-CRUD operations.

Comment: Yes, it have events. I don't want that my repository have dependency from this logger

Comment: Well, there are a lot of ways to avoid having a direct dependency. Expose an event in repository, subscribe from outside, use an interface, etc.